# Can not align navigation bar under header image

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

i've been trying for 2 hours to align the navigation bar nicely under the header image, but it just won't do it.The first 4 list items align in a row, but the last one goes under them, + the nav bar is not centered like i want it to be. I have searched for answers everywhere, and nothing works. Help will be greatly appreciated.
p.s. i am new to css and html so be gentle.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SwKXk23.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: none;
    padding-top: 24px;
}
.headerContent {
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.headerContent a img {
    width: 659px;
    height: 144px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
.nav {
width:750px;
margin:0 auto;
list-style:none;
}
.nav li {
float:left;
}
.nav a {
display:block;
text-align:center;
width:150px; /* fixed width */
text-decoration:none; 
}
.nav ul li{
  height: 40 px;
  background: #A14F53;
}
.nav ul li{
list-style-type: none;
width: 150px;
float: left;
}
.nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
line-height: 40px;
display: block;
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
text-align:center;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
background-color:#F9C1B5;
}
.headerBreak{
width: 100%;
height: o%;
border bottom: 2px solid #128e75;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="background">
<div class="header">
        <div class="headerContent">
            <a href="#">
                <img style="border:0;width:900px;height:250px;" alt="" 
            title="" src="http://i.imgur.com/5NhCbxu.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    <div class="nav">
  <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="Pagina principala.html">Pagina principala</a></li>
    <li><a href="Despre noi.html">Despre noi</a></li>
    <li><a href="Clienţii noştri.html">Clientii nostri</a></li>
    <li><a href="Produse.html">Produse</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contacte.html">Contacte</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="headerBreak"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given the nav bar enough width. Change the .nav rule:

```
.nav {
  width:750px;  <------- adjust this
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style:none;
}
```

I changed your width to 800px instead of 750px and now the menu fits on one line and is centred.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/macg14fs/

Answer (score 1):

Your `.nav` is too narrow for the content so it has wrapped. Press F12 on your browser to discover the interactive debug tools. After that, invest some time in learning about bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

With a Fiddle it would be much easier to know whats the problem, but try this:

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That snippet markup you are using - how did you learn about it and where is it documented?

Comment: You can create snippets with "Ctrl + M" when writting an answer here!